# HTML To PDF High Resolution

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

I want to convert a web page to a high-resolution PDF suitable for printing. How can I do this?

Comment: What language are you using?  What operating system are you using?  Are you aware of PDF printers like CutePDF?

Comment: hi, php is the language. Operating system i am using is Windows Vista. I will try Cute PDF. Thanks

Comment: does the web page utilize any script that it runs to build content? if so you are likely SOL

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in code, have a look at HTML2PDF or FPDF, they are php libraries designed to create PDF documents with code.

If you combine HTML2PDF with PHP's output buffering functions
ie

```
<?php
    ob_start();
?>
    // put all your html in here
<?php
    $data = ob_get_contents();
    require('html2pdf.php');
    $pdf = new HTML2FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->WriteHTML($data);
    $pdf->Output();
 ?>
```

Obviously that is a very rough example but I have used that before within php to generate pdfs. It does have some issues with stylesheets, it seems to ignore most of them. But more control can be gained by using FPDF by itself and manually building the documents.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert web page using browser, you can use sofware in windows like cutepdf, dopdf etc.
but if you want to convert a web page into pdf by php code (on the fly), there are several ways to convert:

1. Using library provided, you can try [html2pdf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phphtml2pdf/) (php). 
   In java / .net a library like [pd4ml](http://pd4ml.com/) can be used (even it is not free).
2. You can use open office converter. It can open multiple doc type, and convert into pdf.  Open office provide API (I have tried in java, not php). The flow is same like you open the document, then convert into pdf, but you just do it in your coding.  Must have open office server daemon to listen the converter via your code. See here http://oodaemon.sourceforge.net/

If you want quick solution in PHP, maybe you can use html2pdf.

The advantage you use open office converter is the output will be same as you see in browser (I already test it use oodaemon). If using library I am not sure 100% it will be same if you open in browser, because the layout is depend on CSS. pd4ml generate layout in pdf base on html and css (has it owns CSS parser I think)

Comment: hi jeft, what i want to convert is using software, currently i tried nitro pdf trial version but when i convert html, it doesn't include any images from that html. And cutepdf, i am trying to convert html, but i don't know how to ? Any good software to test ? I want the high resolution pdf file to print. That's why.

Comment: Sure, you can test doPDF (free), or pdfFactoryPro (not free)

pdf Factory Pro can convert any document (as long as you can print it) to pdf.  open html / word / anything, then click print, and choose pdf factory pro.

if you want to good resolution for image, choose the pdf factory pro properties - graphic tab.  Uncheck downsample images to and uncheck use jpg compression.

It works for me.

Comment: @Jef: I am interested in getting PDF the same as it is in browser (specifically: CSS2.1, images, links). How to do it via OO(daemon)? As I understand, deamon provides the access to OO, which means the output will be in a way how OO renders it.

Answer (score 1):

Try: "[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)" it just work great (and its -open source-). It uses **webkit** engine (used by safari, chrome browsers) and it is very easy to use :

```
wkhtmltopdf stackoverflow.com/questions/1878512/ output.pdf
```

Try it! for Linux and Windows as well. Easy to install. If you use ubuntu, type:

```
aptitude install wkhtmltopdf
```